# Honda Unicorn Electricals Problem due to water

Tags: electrical, honda, motorcycle

I am using Honda CB Unicorn 150cc.

Last day I had to ride my bike through water, after which none of the electricals were working. Only Head lamp will work while the engine is on. After when I removed and connected spark plug, The issue was solved.

After that I had to drive through water again, and the same problem. I tried to reconnect spark plug and fuse. But this time this doesn't works.

There was water in the box which contains filter , which I removed the water and checked everything.

Self start, horn, indicator nothing is working. Battery is fully charged. 
The alarm which is directly connected with battery is working.

Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How old is the bike? 
how deep was the water?

Could be that the HT lead is grounding through the head instead of arcing through the plug due to moisture - my ducati monster had an issue in the rain where the forward cylinder would stop firing because water had got into the plug cap.  You can normally unscrew the plug cap from the HT Lead, clean it, then dry it.  When refitting put a small amount of di-electric grease around the join where the cap meets the lead to make sure that no more water gets in.